# Making a small modification to a itemize environment for arabic presentation with beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, lists, arabic

I would like to change the alignment of lists to the right ( for Arabic presentation ) with beamer.

With the `enumerate` environment we can add some code if it is used frequently, like this :

```
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\def\enumerate{\oldenumerate\raggedleft}
```

In this case we redefine the `enumerate` environment so it's items become aligned to the right.

If we tried to use the same method with the `itemize` environment we can't obtain the same result

```
\let\olditemize\itemize
\def\itemize{\olditemize\raggedleft}
```

The following example illustrates this problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\raggedleft\rightskip\@totalleftmargin} 
\makeatother

\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\def\enumerate{\oldenumerate\RTList}

\let\olditemize\itemize
\def\itemize{\olditemize\RTList}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
نص عربي هنا بالقائمة
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item
نص عربي هنا بالقائمة
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}\RTList
\item
نص عربي هنا بالقائمة
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

We obtain:
[image]
any suggestions  to solve this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the fact that `beamer` redefines `itemize` to have an optional argument, which isn't done for `enumerate`. Thus your attempt to patch `\itemize` adds the code in the wrong place.

With `xpatch` it works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\raggedleft\rightskip\@totalleftmargin} 
\makeatother

\xapptocmd{\enumerate}{\RTList}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\itemize}{\RTList}{}{}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
نص عربي هنا بالقائمة
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item
نص عربي هنا بالقائمة
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}\RTList
\item
نص عربي هنا بالقائمة
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]